# How to retrive data to specific user id from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android applucation. I want to create a payment transaction history in this app. I have create a payment transaction activity and try to retrieve transaction history in a recyclerview. Its working now.

But the issue is the recycler view show the transaction history of all users. I want to show the transaction history in to current user. That means when will I open my transaction history activity I want to see only my transaction history. Now I can see all users transaction history. How I get only my transaction history in my profile. Sorry for my bad english.

This is my code

```
MCC= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PAYTMWITHDRAWAL");
    
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.aswam_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));
    LoadData(categoryId);


}

private void LoadData(String categoryId) {

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PayoutHistoryModel>().setQuery(MCC,PayoutHistoryModel.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PayoutHistoryModel, PayoutHistoryViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PayoutHistoryViewHolder payoutHistoryViewHolder, int i, @NonNull PayoutHistoryModel trollModel) {

            payoutHistoryViewHolder.thrillername.setText(trollModel.getPayoutStatus());

            Picasso.get().load(trollModel.getImage())
                    .into(payoutHistoryViewHolder.thrillersimage);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PayoutHistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.payout_histoy_layout, parent, false);

            return new PayoutHistoryViewHolder(v);
        }
    };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `UID` of the user in each transaction, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to order/filter the data.

For example, if each transaction has a `ownerUID` property you could do something like this:

```
private void LoadData(String categoryId) {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    Query query = MCC.orderByChild("ownerUID").equalTo(uid); // 

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PayoutHistoryModel>()
                       .setQuery(query,PayoutHistoryModel.class).build();
                               // 
    ...
```